# AFNetworking - Request format is not proper when using dictionaries

Tags: ios, httpwebrequest, afnetworking-2

I'm sending a dictionary 'childDetails' which has a dictionary (rewards) as one of its objects.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:url parameters:childDetails constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
```

This "rewards" dictionary has two keys "name" and "value" which looks like `{@"name",@"Reward 1",@"value",@"10"}`.

when this gets posted to the server, the server receives it as follows;

```
 Array
(
    [group_id] => 5
    [name] => John Doe
    [rewards] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sample reward 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 50
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sample Reward 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 10
                )

        )

    [tasks] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Default task one
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Default task two
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Default task five
                )

        )

    [token] => 5332884c2bc8c5
)
```

Any Idea how to fix this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that inorder to get it to work, you have to reformat your dictionary.
In my case I had to change it as;

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
    @"rewards": @[
        {@"reward name",@"reward value"},
        {@"reward name",@"reward value"}
    ]
};;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the "parameters: param of POST: only accepts key/value pairs. Are you sure you don't have to serialize manually your objects first ? 
Can you print the content of "childDetails" please ?

Comment: Child details dictionary looks like this

{
    "group_id" = 5;
    name = "John Doe";
    rewards =     (
                {
            name = "Sample reward 2";
            value = 50;
        },
                {
            name = "Sample Reward 1";
            value = 10;
        }
    );
    tasks =     (
                {
            title = "Default task one";
        },
                {
            title = "Default task two";
        },
                {
            title = "Default task five";
        }
    );
    token = 5332884c2bc8c5;
}

Comment: ok I unsderstand. If you need the same object on the server side, the best way is to serialize the objects yourself. Use JSON format to serialize you rewards item (NSJSONSerialization), and put the JSON string in the rewards property. On server side (It seems you use PHP as server language), you have the json_decode function that can unserialize your string correctly. Don't forget to encode/decode your JSON string for a transfer through URL.

Comment: I have solved the issue that way for now. I was wondering if there is any other proper way of doing it

Comment: Serialization is a good way for complex object transfers. Like base64 for images :)